# Convert RGBA tuple to hex with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

Conversion of rgb to hex is straightforward with matplotlib, but the alpha value seems to be ignored.

For example the output of the two are the same:

```py
mpl.colors.rgb2hex((0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
mpl.colors.rgb2hex((0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8))
```

Which creates the same hex code (`#1a1a1a`), which isn't what I'd like. I'm not sure exactly *which* codes I would like - but I know I would like to be able to have a "lighter" hex code if the alpha value is lower.

Typically I might use an alpha parameter to control the lightness/saturation (sorry I don't have very good language for describing colours) - so it's important that I'm able to do so - but I need to be able to do so by converting RGBA tuples to hex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `keep_alpha=True`:

```
mpl.colors.rgb2hex((0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), keep_alpha=True)
# out: #1a1a1a1a
mpl.colors.rgb2hex((0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8), keep_alpha=True)
# out: #1a1a1acc
```

Comment: ah - thanks. I might have to add an additional question - but presumably the color I see on my screen at the end of this can be represented using a typical 6 char hex code rather than 8 (the program I'm using doesn't understand 8) - is it possible to just "lighten" a hex code similar to what the alpha parameter does here?

Comment: This is how I would do it: convert the RBG/HEX color to HSL, then modify L (the lightness) and finally bring it back to HEX.